# missing ) after argument list else { - i can't see it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pardon for this, i just get this error in console but i can't see it? I may be blind at the moment, anyone please helps me get this error fixed?

says: "missing ) after argument list else {"

```
//run the function for all boxes
$(".box").each(function () {

var thisBox = $(this);
var url = thisBox.href;
var infoBox = $(".info", thisBox);
thisBox.data('height', $(this).height());

thisBox.click(function () {

    if (!thisBox.hasClass("opened")) {
        thisBox.addClass("opened");
        $("img", box).fadeOut("slow", function () {
            infoBox.css({
                "visibility": "visible",
                "height": "auto"
            });

            infoBox.load(url, function () {
                $('.readMore', thisBox).click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter-all');
                    $('#container').isotope({
                        filter: selector
                    });
                    $('#container').isotope('reloadItems');
                    return false;
                });

                $('<a href="#" class="closeBox">Close</a>"').appendTo(infoBox).click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("html, body").animate({
                        scrollTop: 0
                    }, 500);
                    $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
                });

                var newHeight = infoBox.outerHeight(true);
                thisBox.css({
                    "width": "692",
                    "height": newHeight
                });

                infoBox.animate({
                    width: 692,
                    height: newHeight
                }, function () {
                    $('#container').isotope('reLayout', function () {
                        Shadowbox.setup();
                        thisBox.removeClass("loading");
                        infoBox.css({
                            "visibility": "visible"
                        });
                        var videoSpan = infoBox.find("span.video");
                        iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
                            'frameborder': 0,
                            'class': 'tide',
                            'width': '692',
                            'height': '389',
                            'src': 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videoSpan.data("vimeoid") + '?autoplay=0&api=1'
                        });
                        videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);
                    });
                });

            });

        }
        else {
            $(".info").empty();
            $("img", thisBox).fadeIn("slow");
            thisBox.css("width", "230");
            thisBox.height(box.data('height'));
            thisBox.removeClass("opened");
        };

        });
});

});
```

Comment: belongs on http://www.specsavers.co.uk/

Comment: Your editor should be able to collapse code sections and highlight brace pairs. Use that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit comment is a better way of solving this issue, you'll learn more in the end.

Comment: haha - you win  :) - in regards of the down votes.. lol..com'on give me a chance!

Comment: @xanderer: No, he needs to learn how to debug his trivial typos before resorting to asking for free help. He'll learn more in the end, and look better too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i was quite honest and modest and also very auto ironic by saying "i may be blind", i even liked the joke with specsavers.co.uk, but i was simply asking help. Remember: "errare humanum est, perseverare autem diabolicum"

Comment: @rob.m: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: i'm aware of that but by been alone in a room with no colleagues and a bit of coding panic makes you ask stupid questions sometimes :)

Comment: also if you are a designer an not a coder..well..super ciao then! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move one '});' of the bottom before the else:

```
//run the function for all boxes
$(".box").each(function () {

var thisBox = $(this);
var url = thisBox.href;
var infoBox = $(".info", thisBox);
thisBox.data('height', $(this).height());

thisBox.click(function () {

if (!thisBox.hasClass("opened")) {
    thisBox.addClass("opened");
    $("img", box).fadeOut("slow", function () {
        infoBox.css({
            "visibility": "visible",
            "height": "auto"
        });

        infoBox.load(url, function () {
            $('.readMore', thisBox).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter-all');
                $('#container').isotope({
                    filter: selector
                });
                $('#container').isotope('reloadItems');
                return false;
            });

            $('<a href="#" class="closeBox">Close</a>"').appendTo(infoBox).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 500);
                $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
            });

            var newHeight = infoBox.outerHeight(true);
            thisBox.css({
                "width": "692",
                "height": newHeight
            });

            infoBox.animate({
                width: 692,
                height: newHeight
            }, function () {
                $('#container').isotope('reLayout', function () {
                    Shadowbox.setup();
                    thisBox.removeClass("loading");
                    infoBox.css({
                        "visibility": "visible"
                    });
                    var videoSpan = infoBox.find("span.video");
                    iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
                        'frameborder': 0,
                        'class': 'tide',
                        'width': '692',
                        'height': '389',
                        'src': 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videoSpan.data("vimeoid") + '?autoplay=0&api=1'
                    });
                    videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);
                });
            });

        });
    });
    }
    else {
        $(".info").empty();
        $("img", thisBox).fadeIn("slow");
        thisBox.css("width", "230");
        thisBox.height(box.data('height'));
        thisBox.removeClass("opened");
    };
    });
});
```

Comment: by copying this consoles says: "illegal character"

Comment: I guess it's a new error, the brackets should be correct.

Comment: yep- was cached! :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Around line 19 here:

```
$("img", box).fadeOut(
```

You're not closing this function call. You need to close it around line 68 with `});`, as shown below.

```
//run the function for all boxes
$(".box").each(function () {

var thisBox = $(this);
var url = thisBox.href;
var infoBox = $(".info", thisBox);
thisBox.data('height', $(this).height());

thisBox.click(function () {

if (!thisBox.hasClass("opened")) {
    thisBox.addClass("opened");
    $("img", box).fadeOut("slow", function () {
        infoBox.css({
            "visibility": "visible",
            "height": "auto"
        });

        infoBox.load(url, function () {
            $('.readMore', thisBox).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter-all');
                $('#container').isotope({
                    filter: selector
                });
                $('#container').isotope('reloadItems');
                return false;
            });

            $('<a href="#" class="closeBox">Close</a>"').appendTo(infoBox).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 500);
                $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
            });

            var newHeight = infoBox.outerHeight(true);
            thisBox.css({
                "width": "692",
                "height": newHeight
            });

            infoBox.animate({
                width: 692,
                height: newHeight
            }, function () {
                $('#container').isotope('reLayout', function () {
                    Shadowbox.setup();
                    thisBox.removeClass("loading");
                    infoBox.css({
                        "visibility": "visible"
                    });
                    var videoSpan = infoBox.find("span.video");
                    iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
                        'frameborder': 0,
                        'class': 'tide',
                        'width': '692',
                        'height': '389',
                        'src': 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videoSpan.data("vimeoid") + '?autoplay=0&api=1'
                    });
                    videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);
                });
            });

        });

    });
}
    else {
        $(".info").empty();
        $("img", thisBox).fadeIn("slow");
        thisBox.css("width", "230");
        thisBox.height(box.data('height'));
        thisBox.removeClass("opened");
    };

    });
});

});
```

Comment: console says for last line: illegal character "​});"

Comment: removed last }); - it's fine now.